# How to run a Grails 5.1.7 application on a Tomcat 9.0.44 server - HTTP 404

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

My old application with grails version 4.0.5 used to run perfectly. After being forced to update gradle I wasnt able to make it even compile. Then, I created a new project with grails 5.1.7, updated the build.gradle file with the new commands and finally it compiled. The application runs fine in my computer with:

```
grails run-app
```

However, when I make and run the .war file created with the command:

```
grails war
```

in my tomcat server, I get no errors on deployment, but http request always get an **HTTP 404** error.

So I decided to make a new vanilla 5.1.7 grails project and try to make a new clean war. This new project also runs perfectly on my computer with run-app and also is deployed with no errors but also shows the **HTTP 404** error with you try to retrieve a page.

I have been reading on grails documentation that ***grails war*** command makes a embedded container and could cause problems on tomcat:

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/deployment.html#deploymentStandalone

So, I tried to follow the advice and remove from build.gradle:

```
implementation  "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

But still no luck, I keep getting the **HTTP 404** error.

Summary:

My grails 4.0.5 application ran just fine creating the war file with "grails war", so I am not sure if this "embeddable" is the cause of the problem. Due to I get no errors I have no clue.

Any help would be appreciated

Machines and software I've tested:

Machine 1:

- Ubuntu 20.10
- Apache tomcat 9.0.44
- openjdk version "11.0.11"

Machine 2:

- Windows 10
- Apache tomcat 10.0.10
- openjdk version "11.0.11"

Same result on both.

I have also tried to add:
`ext['tomcat.version'] = '10.0.10'` to gradle in case. Not working.

Comment: I have tried to recreate that and cannot.  What JDK is Tomcat running in, and what version of Tomcat is it?

Comment: I am updating my answer with machine and software

Comment: Does every request 404?  If your app provides a custom 404 handling page, is that rendered or are you seeing the default Tomcat 404 page?

Comment: Every dynamic request fails, but you can access to the files in /assets/ folder, I dont know if this means something or not. You see the default TOMCAT 404 error page, not the application custom error page.

Comment: It sounds like it my be a problem related to the root context but it is hard to say without some more info.  If you are able to recreate the issue in a demo app and can share a link to a repo with that code, I would be happy to investigate.  If it starts to look like a bug in Grails, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we will investigate. Best of luck.

Comment: I already submitted the issue. No anwsers yet:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12547
I'm just using a clean new project with  Grails 5.1.7. As I said, it works running with: grails run-app. It is the deployment to Tomcat what is not working. 

In any case please tell me where to send you the  project and I would be happy to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Link to the repository of basic project that works on Tomcat 8.5, but not on Tomcat 9 or Tomcat 10.

https://github.com/vrivon/grails5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to run the Grails 5 application on Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 9 by updating the JVM version from 11 to 16. It seems like Grails 5 doesnt support Tomcat 10.